# Coefficient from Regressing the OLS Residual on X

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, residuals

Say we have an OLS residual $\hat{ϵ}$ from regressing $y$ on $X$. If we were to regress $\hat{ϵ}$ on the same $X$, what would the OLS coefficient be?

If we rearrange the first regression equation for $\hat{ϵ}$, we get
$$
\hat{ϵ} =y−X\hat{β}
$$
but would the OLS coefficient simply be $\hat{β}$?

I suspect I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

The residual vector from OLS estimation is uncorrelated with the explanatory vectors in the regression model, so the estimated coefficient vector from the regression you are proposing would be the **zero vector**.  To see this, first note that the residual vector can be written as:

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}
= [\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{x} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} ] \mathbf{y}.$$

Therefore, using [OLS estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) with the design matrix $\mathbf{x}$ and response vector $\hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}$ gives the estimated coefficient vector:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{{\beta}}_*
&= (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \hat{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \\[6pt]
&= (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} [\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{x} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} ] \mathbf{y} \\[6pt]
&= [(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} - (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} ] \mathbf{y} \\[6pt]
&= [(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} - (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} ] \mathbf{y} \\[6pt]
&= \mathbf{0}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: The observation follows straightforward from using the residual maker $\mathbf e=\mathbf M\mathbf y. $ But I am not getting whether there would be any motivation for doing this at the first place - what is the point of regressing the residuals on $\mathbf X? $ Don't know.

Comment: There is no point --- you will always get estimated coefficients of zero.

Comment: Hm. That's legit. Anyway, +1.